# parsing Special json in python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I need help with parsing json in Python.

json example is:

```
b'{"cluster_name":"ElasticElastic","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary'
b'_shards":397,"active_shards":397,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards"'
b':0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_numb'
b'er":100.0}'
```

How does this output convert to json? Or How to parse this json?

my code is :

```
import requests

res = requests.get("http://localhost:8200/_cluster/health")
for i in res :
    print(i)
```

Comment: How did you get this?  This is JSON, but it has been chopped into 130-byte pieces.  Are you reading this from a socket?  Did you specify a maximum buffer length?  If you concatenate all of these together into one string, and then `s.decode('utf-8')`, you can pass it to `json.loads`,

Answer (score 2):

What you shared is Python's representation of a bytes value - you can `.decode()` it and then pass it to `json.loads` if you `import json`.

This is probably what you're after, although you probably got that data from somewhere else that you can use instead of `data`:

```py
import json

data = b'{"cluster_name":"ElasticElastic","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary' \
       b'_shards":397,"active_shards":397,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards"' \
       b':0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_numb' \
       b'er":100.0}'

d = json.loads(data.decode())

print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'cluster_name': 'ElasticElastic', 'status': 'green', 'timed_out': False, 'number_of_nodes': 1, 'number_of_data_nodes': 1, 'active_primary_shards': 397, 'active_shards': 397, 'relocating_shards': 0, 'initializing_shards': 0, 'unassigned_shards': 0, 'delayed_unassigned_shards': 0, 'number_of_pending_tasks': 0, 'number_of_in_flight_fetch': 0, 'task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis': 0, 'active_shards_percent_as_number': 100.0}
```

That's a dictionary, which you can then access as usual:

```py
print(d['cluster_name'])
```

Result:

```
ElasticElastic
```

Note that, depending on the encoding of the `bytes` data you receive, `.decode()` may work, but if it doesn't it probably means the data is not encoded with the default `'utf-8'` encoding Python uses and you'll need to tell the `.decode()` method what encoding to use instead.

Based on your comment, you need something like:

```py
import json
import requests

res = requests.get("localhost:8200/_cluster/health")
data = res.content

d = json.loads(data.decode())

print(d['cluster_name'])
```

Comment: You probably want to add that to the question, if the answer as provided doesn't help - that way, you can format it like code. Sharing code in comments doesn't generally work very well.